# Query optimization with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( a INT(10), b char(10));
```

add two indexes:

```
alter table test add key aa (a), add key bb (b);
```

insert some rows:

```
insert into test values (132,'logi');
insert into test values (322,'koko');
insert into test values (32,'kola');
```

etc...

You can test with a little number of rows BUT in my application i will have a hundred million of rows so what i am going to ask makes sense: 
So, let's say that i want to execute two queries:

```
1) explain select * from test where b like "frif%";
2) explain select * from test where a like "32%";
```

The first uses the index bb since b is a char, while the second doesn't use the index aa since a is just an INT (and i treat it like a char!).
How can i make the second query execute as the first and search for numbers like "some_number%" and make that a query of range type and not ALL (as explain shows).

Comment: int is converted into string that's why index is not working.

Comment: Perhaps a function based index on A casting it to Character data.  Thereby creating an index which the engine will likely use.

Comment: xQbert, i tried to do what you suggest with CAST function but something like this: (explain) select * from test where cast(a as CHAR) like "32%"; does not work!!!

Comment: This might work though: (explain) select CAST(a as CHAR) from test where a like "32%";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are treating the number as a character string, then store it that way.  It sounds like the number is a code of some sort.  Although consisting of numbers, it is really just the name of something (such as an account number).

If the number is fixed length, say 5, then you can do:

```
where a >= 32000 and a < 33000;
```

You could extend this idea for different lengths:

```
where a >= 32 and a < 33 or
      a >= 320 and a < 330 or
      a >= 3200 and a < 3300 or
      a >= 30000 and a < 33000
```

Comment: Thanks! I also think that this is a solution, but it can not be applied to my problem because the field 'a' (INT) in my application is a BIG INT and it contains numbers with >12 digits, so if i changed it to a VARCHAR let's say, i am going to have storage overhead!

Comment: @JohnZobolas . . . Why can't this be applied to your situation?  You would just have `where a >= 3000000000000 and a < 3300000000000` or whatever.

Comment: Of course and it can be applied: but what i mean with storage overhead is this: i have a number num: BIGINT which takes 8 bytes to store. If i declare it in the table definition as a VARCHAR, it will need 1 byte for every digit (digit=char in this occasion). So for a number of >8 digits (i have a LOT of them) i will need more than 8 bytes for it (e.g. for num: VARCHAR having 14 chars-digits, i need 14 bytes of storage, which is TOO much).